# How can i use DOM events inside my javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to make a function inside my class, where by pressing the ArrowUp key, it will become true. However, it just says: "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined?

```
class Boks{
  constructor(x,y,w,h,r,k){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.r = r;
    this.k = k;
  }

  visSnake(){
    rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h)
  }

  moveSnake(){
    this.x = this.x + speed;
  }

  keyb(event){
    if(event.key === "ArrowUp"){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

My guess is that I have to define some sort of DOM event key in the constructor or parameter to the constructor, but i dont know how?

Comment: How does `keyb()` get called?

Comment: In [*p5.js*](https://p5js.org/reference/) you've just to define the function [`keyPressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed). You don't need to define any DOM event, p5.js does the job for you, you've just to "use" the existing callbacks, which are well documented

Comment: could you also paste the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [*p5.js*](https://p5js.org/reference/) you've just to define the function [`keyPressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed) which is automatically called, if an button is pressed. You don't need to define any DOM event, p5.js does the job for you, you've just to "use" the existing callbacks, which are well documented.
I recommend to read [p5.js - Get Started](https://p5js.org/get-started/).

If you want to evaluate if the <kbd>UP</kbd> key is pressed, then you can evaluate the state of the built in variable [`keyIsPressed`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsPressed) and [`keyCode`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyCode) in `draw`:

```js
function draw() {

    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        // [...]
    }

    // [...]
}
```

See the short example:

```js
let x=0, y=0, w=20, h=20;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth-20,window.innerHeight-20)
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
    frameRate(10);
}

function draw(){
    
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
        if (x > 0) { 
            x -= w;
        }
    }
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW){
        if (x < width-w) { 
            x += w;
        }
    }   
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        if (y > 0) { 
            y -= h;
        }
    }
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW){
        if (y < height-h) { 
            y += h; 
        }
    }

    background(0);
    stroke(255);
    fill(255);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```